# Error glibc detected free(): invalid next size(fast)

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, memory-leaks

So I'm writing a dynamic array class and I'm running into issues with (I believe) setting up a temporary array to hold the values, then changing the size of the current array, it throws me the glibc detected free(): invalid next size(fast) error. I realize that this either means I'm writing outside of an array's bounds somewhere, or I'm trying to free memory that I don't have allocated to me, but I can't seem to find where the issue is.. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've been looking over my code for about 2 hours and can't seem to find a way to fix the issue besides removing the delete statements altogether which isn't much of a solution since that just causes memory leaks. And I'm new to C++ so I apologize for any dumb mistakes/syntax

ArrayList.cpp

```
#include "ArrayList.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int& ArrayList::operator[](unsigned int i){
    return foo[i];
}

int ArrayList::size(){
    return numElements;
}
void ArrayList::downArray(){
    int* bar = foo; //temp array to hold values while I decrease the size
    capacity /= 2;
    delete foo;
    foo = new int[capacity]; //don't I lose the original pointer here? So why does it throw an error when I try to delete foo, as if I haven't allocated that memory?
    for(int i = 0; i < capacity;i++){
        foo[i] = bar[i];    
    }

}

void ArrayList::upArray(){

    int* bar = foo; //temp array to hold values while I increase the size
    delete foo;
    foo = new int[capacity*2]; //same thing here
    foo = bar;
    for(int i = capacity; i < capacity*2;i++){
        foo[i] = 0;
    }
    capacity *=2;
}

void ArrayList::push_back(int m){
    if(numElements == capacity) //full, double foo
        upArray();
    foo[numElements] = m;
    numElements++;
}

void ArrayList::erase(int m){
    bool notFound = true;   
    int i = 0;
    while(notFound)
        if(foo[i] == m){
            notFound = false;    //Ha! Found you!
            for(int j = i; j+1 < capacity; j++){
                foo[j] = foo[j+1]; //moves everything to right of m one spot left
            }
        }
        else
            i++; //keep looking
}

string ArrayList::toString(){
    stringstream sobj;
    string x;
    sobj << "[";
    for(int i = 0; i < numElements; i++){
        if(i == numElements-1) //last iteration, avoids output displaying [1,2,3,4,]
            sobj << foo[i];
        else
            sobj << foo[i] << ",";
    }
    sobj << "]";
    sobj >> x;
    return x;
}

ArrayList::ArrayList(){
    capacity = 1;   
    numElements = 0;
    foo = new int[1];
    foo[0] = 0;
}

ArrayList::~ArrayList(){
    //delete foo; //is this not the proper place to call it?
    cout << "Destructor called" << endl;
}
```

ArrayList.h

```
#ifndef _ARRAYLIST_H_
#define _ARRAYLIST_H_
#include <string>
class ArrayList
{
 public:
    ArrayList();
    ~ArrayList();

    int& operator[](unsigned int i); // int& ArrayList::operator[](unsigned int i){....}

    void push_back(int m); 
    void erase(int m);
    std::string toString();
    int size();

 private: 
  void downArray();
    void upArray();

 private:
  int capacity, numElements;
    int* foo;
};

#endif
```

main function

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    ArrayList arr;

    for (int i=1;i<=50;i++)
    {
        arr.push_back(i);
    }

    cout << "Should contain numbers 1..50, is ";

    cout << arr.toString() << endl;
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide the flow of method calls. I have seen multiple new for foo.

Comment: just updated, sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code has multiple problems:

```
int* bar = foo; //temp array to hold values while I increase the size
delete foo;
foo = new int[capacity*2]; //same thing here
foo = bar;
for(int i = capacity; i < capacity*2;i++){
    foo[i] = 0;
}
capacity *=2;
```

Here are some issues with this code:

`delete foo;`
Once you call `delete`, the memory is freed. So you can no longer use `bar` as it points to freed memory.

`foo = bar;`
You just allocated memory and saved the pointer in `foo`, this line throws away that memory address and sets `foo` back to what it was.

One way to do the `upArray` is to allocate the new memory, copy the data across, then free the old memory.

```
int* bar = new int[capacity*2]; // new array to hold values
// Copy the data
for(int i = 0; i < capacity;i++){
    bar[i] = foo[i];
}
// Zero out the rest
for(int i = capacity; i < capacity*2;i++){
    bar[i] = 0;
}
delete foo;  // delete the old memory
foo = bar;   // point to the new memory.
capacity *=2;
```

Also note that as you have your own allocated pointers in your member variables, you must create a copy constructor and assignment operator (see Rule Of Three). Otherwise any code that makes a copy of an `ArrayList` object will copy the pointer, leading to multiple deletes of the same memory.

Answer (score 0):

```
`ArrayList arr;` will call the constructor 

ArrayList::ArrayList(){
    capacity = 1;   
    numElements = 0;
    foo = new int[1];
    foo[0] = 0;
}
```

Which is creating foo of size 1.
then

```
 for (int i=1;i<=50;i++)
    {
        arr.push_back(i);
    }
```

push_back method can only insert one elemnt(because size is 1). 
Solution : change the for loop `for (int i=1;i<=1;i++)` so toString should print only one element.I did't compiled your source code. It's my basic understanding.